# restore version of file with minio-js

Tags: minio

Is there any way to restore a specific version of a file on a minio server with minio-js on a bucket with active versioning?
On the web console there is a button to restore, but I didn't found any docs to do this with the minio-js client.

Comment: I can get Object(text) file with the version ID by Postman API call but I try to call it by minio-js for local minio server. I failed did you can access a local minio server by 'minio-js' or remote mino server?

Comment: This is documentation in [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/javascript/API.html#getobjecttagging-bucketname-objectname-getopts-callback)

Comment: Thanks. I know the documentation and can access the different versions, but do I have to load a version and reupload it to restore an older version?
The js client has much less functionality then for example the java client.

Comment: I can do it via `REST-API` by Postman not `minio-js` with local minio server. If you want to see demo, I can post in here.

Comment: That would be great if you have a sample, thanks.

Comment: I will post after return home in tonight.

Comment: I posted it by curl command, let me know it is looking for even if not `minio-js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not succeed to restore call using by `minio-js`
If someone success to call by `minio-js` let me know or post here.

But I can restore the REST API call by curl.

```
curl --cookie <cookie file name> \
--silent \
-X "PUT" 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/buckets/version-demo/objects/restore?prefix=<prefix id>&version_id=<restore version id>'
```

`<cookie file name>`: save a cookie file a login command by curl

`<prefix id>`: will display the browser

`<restore version id>`: Can get version list command by curl

#### Demo

Launching local `minio` by docker compose, detail step in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75170434/how-to-authenticate-in-rest-request-to-minio/75175967#75175967)

#### Access by Browser

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

[image]

Will create `demo` object and save a text-data.txt file with two versions.
Will restore v1 text file after V1 and V2 store, total of three versions

```
V1 -> V2 -> V3 (restored V1, it means save V1)
```

Object(Bucket) Name

```
demo
```

You must to enable `Versioning` in UI

[image]

[image]

text file name

```
text-data.txt
```

[image]

Version 1's content

```
I am v1 file, I have single line.
```

Version 2's content

```
I am v2 file
I have two lines.
```

After upload two version file with sav file name.
You can see the version ID from UI.

And Browser's address editor can get the `prefix` or `path`
It needs to use the version restore and delete API call.

My demo's value is

```
dGV4dC1kYXRhLnR4dA==
```

[image]

#### Admin credential

```
user name: admin
password: admin-strong
```

I will use this to save the cookie file.

#### Save Cookie by curl

The cookies.txt will save and it includes `access token`

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/login' \
--silent \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--cookie-jar cookies.txt \
--data '{"accessKey":"admin","secretKey":"admin-strong"}'
```

[image]

Now ready to call Get version list and Restore API with that `cookie.txt` file.

#### Get the version list for the `text-data.txt` file of `demo` bucket

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt --silent --location 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/buckets/demo/objects?with_versions=true' | json_pp
```

Result Image

[image]

Result JSON

```
{
   "objects" : [
      {
         "etag" : "2f2039d664ae526ff63e13bd24b3b487",
         "is_latest" : true,
         "last_modified" : "2023-08-03T03:54:26Z",
         "name" : "text-data.txt",
         "size" : 31,
         "version_id" : "49ad9f0b-95b4-4191-a850-5bf62aa6062b"
      },
      {
         "etag" : "8dd501a7d924867c24793acccc40b9ec",
         "last_modified" : "2023-08-03T03:53:58Z",
         "name" : "text-data.txt",
         "size" : 33,
         "version_id" : "d99bbbbf-5413-42f5-9a8d-265709018a2a"
      }
   ],
   "total" : 2
}
```

#### Restore the `text-data.txt` version 1 after V2 text.

So before API call status V1 -> V2
After API call V1 -> V2 -> V3 (restore with V1 content)

Version id set with Version 1's ID

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt --silent -X "PUT" 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/buckets/demo/objects/restore?prefix=dGV4dC1kYXRhLnR4dA==&version_id=d99bbbbf-5413-42f5-9a8d-265709018a2a'
```

Before Restore
[image]

After Restore

Terminal: restore and get list.

[image]

UI: confirm API call is correct or not.

[image]

This is version 3 content

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description.