# Can't find JWT token in my Browser (Web Storage)

Tags: firefox, jwt, authorization, token

The application base on JWT token as authorization. As my knowledge it should be storage in web storage of my my Firefox.

I've checked cookies, local/session storage and I can't find it there. The authorization token must be somewhere because is attached to my every HTTP request.

I won't fetch it from header, I just wanna be sure if its stored in browser.

is it possible that Firefox hide auth tokens or JWT is client-side generated (yea, it would be security vuln then).

Comment: There are many ways to save access token to  browser. which web site URL are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you Bench for your answer. The URL and the application is non-public, internal. Could you please expand your thought?

Comment: or could you share any article? Most of them mentioned only web-storage or JS variables.

Comment: Not directly match your question but one of related [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787003/restore-version-of-file-with-minio-js/76824907#76824907) to save a cookie the access token into local file by curl.

Comment: Hey Bench, my point isn't save the access token. I want to check where it is stored. If it's client-side generated, then the application is really vulnerable.